# SSRS Break after n occurrences of group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to group an SSRS report so that each page breaks naturally around the 11 inch mark.

It looks as though you cannot dynamically set the `Interactive Height` property so I have set it to 0 and am applying page breaks to the dataset.

I am making the assumption that roughly every 3 users will take up about a full page. I want to break after every 3 EmployeeID groupings. I have only seen breaks which consider the `RowCount`, which is inconsistent per user in my dataset. A user can have 1 or Many rows.

> How can I break after 3 occurences of an SSRS sub group?

Here is an image of the current grouping I have: 
[image: SSRS Grouping]

I need the Header (title, Period and blank line) to appear on every new page.
On every page I want to take up as much of the 11 inches as possible, but I am willing to settle on simply stating that we will break after every 3 occurrences of the `EmployeeID` group.

The `EmployeeID2` group may not be necessary, it was implemented when I was experimenting with `RowNumber` breaks.

There are two possible solutions to my issue as I see it:

1. Somebody tells me how to set a parameterized Page Break every 11 inches
2. Somebody tells me how to set a parameterized Page Break every `n` occurrences of an SSRS subgroup

Finally, additional clarification:

> I need a parameter which toggles `PageBreak`. If the `PageBreak Parameter` is set to `False`, the Header will appear only once and all Employees will display as with `InterActive Height = 0`. If the `PageBreak Parameter` is set to `True`, the Header will appear at the top of every new page, and every page will contain 3 Employees.

I tried implementing a Grouping field in my `Stored Procedure` which assigns every 3 Employees an incrementing Group ID using the code below, however this query which runs in 3 seconds is now freezing SSRS, so I am hoping to achieve the grouping using SSRS functions.

TSQL Grouping Logic:

```
,EmpRank AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        EmployeeID
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY FormattedName) AS 'EmpCounter'
    FROM FilteredData
)

,EmpGrouping AS (
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,((EmpCounter -1 ) / 3) AS 'EmpGroup'
    FROM EmpRank
    GROUP BY ((EmpCounter - 1) / 3)
        ,EmployeeID
)

SELECT
    FilteredData.*
    ,EmpGrouping.EmpGroup
FROM FilteredData
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmpGrouping
        ON EmpGrouping.EmployeeID = FilteredData.EmployeeID
ORDER BY EmpGroup, EmployeeID
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please change that image link to inline image. most viewer over here prefer that. thanks

Comment: @KashifQureshi You can do that yourself, but there's no need now :)

Comment: @Archer lol, I know, usually i do. But Today I am not in mood

Answer (score 1):

The TSQL grouping logic worked in the end. Visual Studio had been crashing when I tried that grouping yesterday, but today its not...

In any case, the solution was to create a new field which grouped the employees as I wanted, and then I grouped upon that within SSRS.  I still do not know how to group based on page height but at least I was able to group based on occurrences of the sub group